# Can node-red html be edite elsewhere?

Tags: html, editor, node-red

I'm developing a node-red application right now that uses a html response. The html uses google maps, visual indicators and websockets. It is very hard to debug this system through node-red's little html editor. Is there a way to edit the html file through any normal editor (e.g. vs code) and then deploy the application again to see the effect ?

One solution that came to my mind was to read from an external file using the file node and return it as html, put I don't know if that works. Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create and edit static resources (html/css files etc) however you'd like and then serve them from Node-RED.

You have two options for serving static content:

1. create corresponding `HTTP In -> File In -> HTTP Response` flows for each file you want to serve
2. or use the `httpStatic` property in your `settings.js` file to identify a directory whose content should be automatically served by the runtime.

Comment: your first solution is what I wrote at the question, right ? So it can be done ?

Comment: I would recommend looking at the httpStatic option - saves you from having to create individual flows for each resource.

Comment: (and yes... I included it in the answer because it does work)